# "Transforming" Function Arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, arguments

I'm writing C++ class that interfaces with a library. The library has a bunch of functions that look like the following:

**Library.h**

```
int FunctionA(int deviceNumber, ...);
int FunctionB(int deviceNumber, ...);
int FunctionC(int deviceNumber, ...);
int FunctionD(int deviceNumber, ...);
int FunctionE(int deviceNumber, ...);
```

Each instance of my C++ class has an associated `deviceNumber` which never changes, so I have `deviceNumber` stored as a member variable, and every time I call a library function, I pass the member in as the function call's first argument.

This is fine, and there's no real reason for me to change the way it is. But out of curiosity, I was wondering if C++ had any mechanism to "transform" arguments that would let me avoid passing the same argument in every call. The obvious way to accomplish this is to overload everything. Let's say my class is called `Foo`:

**Foo.cpp**

```
int Foo::FunctionA(...) {
    // deviceNumber_ is a const member
    return ::FunctionA(deviceNumber_, ...);
}
```

The only problem is that this requires a method for each function call, so as the library grows, it gets more and more annoying without a code generator.

Is there any general way to provide the overloading behaviour without actually overloading the functions? Is there a mechanism in C++ to "expand" an argument into multiple arguments? I'm imagining it would look like:

```
// These two calls are equivalent
FunctionA(deviceNumber, ...);
FunctionA(Magic(...));
// Magic() expands the arguments, adding deviceNumber
```

Even if the solution is much uglier and less readable than leaving everything alone, I'm curious if it's possible. After searching around, variadic templates seem to be the closest match, but I can't really wrap my head around how they could be used to accomplish this.

Comment: How about make deviceNumber to private value. and make base class.
then inherited member function is no need to use devicenumber.

Comment: Would a macro work? `#define MAGIC(...) deviceNumber_, __VA_ARGS__`

Comment: Macro is also good choice for very little difference

Comment: @cpplover-SlwEssencial - Can you show an example of what this would look like? Wouldn't I still need to overload each library call manually?

Comment: @KerrekSB - Wow, I had absolutely no idea that variadic macros were a thing. That macro seems to work perfectly. I'll leave everything alone since I can't get away with sneaking any preprocessor magic into the code, but that's definitely a cool solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be happy with a generic relay function:

[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b762f0f3a25561b3)

```
#include <iostream>

int    foo1(int device_number, const char*) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; return device_number*42; }
double foo2(int device_number)              { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; return device_number*3.14159; }

struct facade {
    facade(int dn) : device_number(dn) {}

    template <typename F, typename... A>
        auto call(F&& f, A&&... args) const {
            return std::forward<F>(f)(device_number, std::forward<A>(args)...);
        }

  private:
    int device_number;
};

int main() {

    facade dev(2);

    std::cout << dev.call(foo1, "yes ma'am") << "\n";
    std::cout << dev.call(foo2) << "\n";

}
```

Comment: And [if Bjarne gets his way](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4174.pdf), we can spell the latter as `foo1(dev, "yes ma'am")` and it'll look uniform and convenient :-) Or we adopt [N4165](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4165.pdf) and the OP can say `deviceNumber.functionA(...)`... The mind boggles.

Comment: Oh.. good usage of template reference. 
thanks for showing this way. but very complex and difficult. ^^

Answer (score 1):

I would probably choose a marco in the cpp file as the easiest solution (strictly in the cpp file though)

Variadic templates could help here too. However it sounds like you are doing something embedded and that might be an issue.

Also, I'm not sure if you mean that each FunctionA is overloaded or FunctionA refers to exactly one function.

Anyway, my template solution will help if there are multiple FunctionAs

```
template<typename... Args>
int Foo::FunctionA(Args&& ...args) {
    return ::FunctionA(deviceNumber_, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: Variadic templates aren't an issue. The library controls an embedded device, but I'm calling the library from a desktop program with full C++11 support. Also, FunctionA isn't overloaded. I referred to my solution of wrapping the global FunctionA call with an equivalent method as "overloading", but I'm not sure if this is a correct way to phrase it.

Answer (score 0):

I put pseudo code , for C++ type structure.

Class Prototype might be following forms.

```
class Foo {
    private private_member_of_deviceNumber;
    ....
    int FunctionA(...);
    ....
}
```

Foo Class constructor will assign deviceNumber to private member variable.

```
class Foo::Foo(int deviceNumber) { 
    int private_member_of_deviceNumber = deviceNumber;
}
```

Foo Class member FunctionA(...) will like this form.

```
int Foo::FunctionA(...) {
   return ::FunctionA( private_member_of_deviceNumber , ...);
}
```

How about like this way?

Comment: This is what I was trying to get at with my `Foo.cpp` example. This works, but if the library has a bunch of functions with similar prototypes, I'd end up defining a ton of methods to overload them. I was wondering if there's a way to do this with a fixed overhead, regardless of how many library functions there are.

Comment: @Matt base form is this way and you need to remove same time-consuming job copy& paste bunch of library code. 
then, You use macro and template , other answer posted it.
Good Job!